# Eclipse search pop-up is always maximized on MacOS

Tags: eclipse, macos, macos-high-sierra, eclipse-kepler

For some reason all my eclipse popups always open in maximized (tabbed) mode. I can't seem to fix this. For some legacy reasons I'm stuck with Eclipse Kepler and cannot upgrade.

Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 2 Build id: 20140224-0627

MacOS version: High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65)

Using JDK 1.8

I have tried:

1. Cleaning up eclipse persisted state
2. Creating new workspace
3. Cleaning up metadata
4. Cleaning up .eclipse folder in user's folder
5. I drag the window and resize it, but the state is not saved.
6. I also tried restoring old copy of eclipse I had backed-up.

Is it possible that MacOS might have saved the state of the window for Eclipse App. This started happening when I had full screened the Eclipse window.
Can somebody help me with this?

Here are some screenshots:
[image: Find resources popup]
[image: Search popup]

Comment: This doesn't happen with the current Eclipse and I imagine there are very few people left running Kepler on macOS. Why do you think you are stuck on Kepler?

Comment: Eclipse Osgi, some custom plugins, eclipse based build (.classpath and .project and everything), Eclipse bukminster, no build tool(maven) to build the projects. Of course people who did this have left the company.